# Visual Studio XAML Intellisense not working until I open a tag

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, intellisense

[Intellisense working when I open a tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo920.png)

[But I want to use Intellisense without opening a tag. Like in the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0mh8.png)

I am able to do this with ctrl + Space combination. Is there any way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot get what you want so far. And XAml Intellisense is special and it should work with `<` and `>`. So invoke the Intellisense should be with them. There is no such automatic way as you wished by default.

**After all**, it is not the type of c# or c++ code that can type some word to invoke Intellisense. And Xaml Intellisense is not flexible as you expected.

VS does not design that by default and there is no such vs extensions I found to realize so far.

If you still want your feature, you could [suggest a feature on the DC Forum](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=8) and then share the link here when you finish it. Anyone who is interested in it including us will vote it to help get the feedback from the **Microsoft** as soon as possible.